# Application Support directory, some apps are using tons of space!

Tags: macos

After running out of space multiple times, I started researching and putting a strategy to permanently fix this issue.

In the end I found that Application Support is an important directory for most of apps, but I've a directory called **Google** with 2.2 GB size. Most probably this is for Chrome only. What does this directory include and what will happen if I delete it?

Including information about directories and their sizes:

[image: Including information about directories and their sizes***]

Comment: Google will also contain info for Drive You need to give more detail as to the sizes of the subdirectories

Comment: @Mark I've updated the question with a photo, I don't use Drive, I have Chrome and its extensions, plus AFT for my android phone.

Comment: The next column split for Default would be useful

Comment: Updated again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be local storage, used by websites to store temporary files. [This article](http://www.ghacks.net/2015/06/24/hard-drive-filling-up-check-chromes-file-system-folder/) explains how you can use Chrome itself to inspect the contents in more detail.

Seems like it should be safe enough to delete (the article also describes a Chrome extension that can safely do that), but as always, make sure you have a backup just in case.

Comment: The solution of clearing browser data didn't actually do anything, the directory is still having the same size as before!
I will try the other solution which is making a backup of this directory and then deleting it to see how Chrome will behave.

Comment: Deleting the directory didn't create any problems, I am doing the same every once and a while, thanks for the solution.